# Parameterization of $SU(4)$

Tags: lie-groups, matrices

I'm trying to understand how to represent unitary matrices of dimension higher than $2$. It is clear to me that $SU(2)$ can be represented with two complex numbers $a, b$
$$U = \begin{bmatrix} a & b \\ -b^* & a^* \end{bmatrix}$$
with $|a|^2 + |b|^2 = 1$.

I've read that $SU(n)$ has dimension $n^2 - 1$ so I would expect to be able to use eight complex numbers (with normalization constraint), is there a nice form of such matrix and normalization in terms of such numbers?

I've heard about the generalized Gellmann matrices but I'm not sure it is relevant.

Comment: $4^2-1$ was 15 this morning. How could 4 complex numbers help?

Comment: @BugsBunny seems like I wanted to reinvent math, thanks. I meant to say 8

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Euler angle parametrization for $SU(4)$ is given by [formula (5)](http://arxiv.org/abs/math-ph/0202002v7), with $4^2-1=15$ real parameters $\alpha_1,\dots,\alpha_{15}$ and "basis" Hermitian matrices $\lambda_1,\dots,\lambda_{15}$ given by formula (A1) in Appendix A of that paper.

There is also a [generalized Euler angle parametrization for $SU(N)$](https://web2.ph.utexas.edu/%7Egsudama/pub/2002_001.pdf).